# Can a runner run back to their original base on a forced play?

Tags: baseball

I have a question about baseball rules:

- forced play, R1 goes in 2B, BR in 1B > R1 misses 3B can he retreat to
  3B and after to 2B? And BR can retreat, after is on 3B, to 1B?

Comment: Can you clarify the start of this play? I assume R1 starts at first when the ball is put in play, or there is no force. Are you asking what happens if R1 realizes they missed 3rd before they score, but after BR has reached third?